# Как отбросить секунды в Javascript либо в запросе PostgreSQL?

Tags: javascript, postgresql

```
var dt = new Date()
```

берется текущее время и дата, включая секунды, и при передаче `dt` на сервер передается дата-время формата `2015-10-15T12:50:11.757Z` Мне же нужно `2015-10-15T9:00` либо `2015-10-15 09:00`, т.е. отбросить секунды, миллисекунды и т.п. - для последующей записи в базу данных (тип `timestamp without timezone`). Также в принципе можно сделать преобразование и в самом запросе. 
Т.е. как в итоге получить дату-время формата `YYYY-mm-dd HH:MM`?

В Javascript переменная должна быть именно типа `Date()`, а не строка, т.к. такой тип требуется для других скриптов, которые работают с этой переменной - на сайте пользователь выставляет свое время и дату, и они обновляются в этой переменной. А секунды, естественно, остаются прежними. Можно отбросить секунды в самой переменной, можно их обнулить, можно в запросе postgresql сделать преобразование, либо отредактировать тип или что-то еще для поля, в которое идет запись (у него сейчас тип `timestamp without timezone` - т.е. `2015-10-15T12:50:11.757Z` записывается как есть). В итоге в поле в таблице должна быть дата-время до минут, все остальное либо отброшено (что предпочтительнее), либо обнулено.

Comment: Возьмите прямо на сервере в PostgreSQL текущее время. Чего его с компьютера пользователя-то гонять?

Comment: @Visman время выставляется пользователем на сайте. Вначале берется new Date(), и у него выставляются время и дата на основе того, что введено пользователем. Поэтому брать время на сервере не вариант)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Javascript**

```
var a = '2015-10-15T12:50:11.757Z'.replace(/\:\d{2}\.\d+Z$/, ''); a;
"2015-10-15T12:50"
```

**Postresql**

```
select date_trunc('minute', '2015-10-15T12:50:11.757Z'::timestamp);
     date_trunc      
---------------------
 2015-10-15 12:50:00

select to_char('2015-10-15T12:50:11.757Z'::timestamp, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:00');
       to_char       
---------------------
 2015-10-15 12:50:00
(1 row)

select to_char('2015-10-15T12:50:11.757Z'::timestamp, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI');
     to_char      
------------------
 2015-10-15 12:50
```

**Но.** Если тебе нужно записывать в БД поле типа "timestamp without timezone" то какой смысл обрезать секунды, если Postgresql понимает твой исходный формат данных ('2015-10-15T12:50:11.757Z'::timestamp)?..

Comment: менять время как строку не вариант, т. к. дата редактируется из формы, т.е. изначальному new Date() выставляются время и дата пользователем на сайте. Мне нужно именно переменную типа Date(), но либо с обнулением всего, что после минут, либо отбрасыванием этой части, либо уже на сервере в запросе убрать эту часть. Поэтому второй вариант с постгресом подходит больше, спасибо, попробую date_trunc. Да, в  поле типа "timestamp without timezone" без проблем записывается такое время, как сейчас у меня, но по заданию секунд быть не должно, т.е. они либо должны обнуляться, либо отбрасываться

Comment: а можно ли установить тип поля вместо timestamp without timezone или ограничение, или формат какой-то для поля, чтобы секунды отбрасывались?

Comment: спасибо, сделал в запросе преобразование даты при помощи `date_trunc('minute', ...)`

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте:

```
    var time = new Date();
    dt = time.toISOString()
```

Так как вы будете заносить данные в PostgreSQL, он всё-равно будет добавлять секунды и временную зону, так что этот метод должен вам помочь

**UPD**

если не поможет можете сделать так:

```
var time = new Date();
dt = time.toISOString().replace(/\.\d+Z/,'')
```

Comment: Нет такого метода.

Comment: Вы правы, обновил, не там проверял_))

Answer (score -2):

Знаю как в Android, может тоже поможет, Java же

```
Date d=new Date(new Date().getTime());
String s=new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy/kk:mm").format(d);
```

Comment: Это разве javascript?

Comment: @Visman "Знаю как в андроид, может тоже поможет, ява жи"